# Python Web Server

Tags: python, google-app-engine, apple-push-notifications

I want a simple python web server for the following use case:
I want to write a simple server that will accept HTTP requests from my application running on Google App Engine.
The server will accept HTTP requests, and then send iphone notifications. (Basically, I need this extra server to account for the lack of socket support in google app engine).

I guess I need the server to be able to maintain this persistent connection with Apple's Push Notification Service. So I'll need to have some sort of thread always open for this. So I need some sort of web server that can accept the request pass it off to the other thread with the persistent connection to APNS.

Maybe multiple processes and one of pythons queuing tools to communicate between them? Accept the HTTP request, then enqueue a message to the other process?

I was wondering what someone with a bit of experience would suggest. I'm starting to think that maybe even writing my own simple server is a good option (http://fragments.turtlemeat.com/pythonwebserver.php).

Comment: [Notifo](http://notifo.com) allows you to do what you want, and is free to 10k pushes a month. You might also keep tabs on [Issue 1164](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=1164)

Answer (score 4):

One option would be the (appropriately named) [SimpleHTTPServer](http://docs.python.org/library/simplehttpserver.html), which is part of the Python standard library. Another, more flexible but more complicated option would be to write your server in [Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/).

Answer (score 3):

I've been writing simple http servers using gevent and bottle -- an example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import gevent.monkey
gevent.monkey.patch_all()

import bottle
bottle.debug(True)

import gevent.wsgi

from bottle import route, run, request, response, static_file, abort

@route('/echo')
def echo():
    s = request.GET.get('s', 'o hai')
    return '<html><head><title>echo server</title></head><body>%s</body></html>\r\n' % (s)

@route('/static/:filename')
def send_static(filename):
    root = os.getcwd() + '/static'
    return static_file(filename, root=root)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = bottle.app()
    wsgi_server = gevent.wsgi.WSGIServer(('0.0.0.0', 8000), app)
    print 'Starting wsgi search on port 8000'
    wsgi_server.serve_forever()
```

So you could write a simple server that sticks a job into a Queue (see gevent.queue) and have another worker greenlet that handles reading requests from the queue and processing them...